# MATLAB automatically assigns unwanted dimensions to a dynamically updated cell array

Tags: matlab, indexing, default-value, cell-array, is-empty

I want to generate a 3D cell array called `timeData` so that `timeData(:,:,a)` for some integer `a` is an nx1 matrix of data, and the number of rows `n` varies with the value of `a` in a 1:1 correspondence. To do this, I am generating a 2D array of data called `data` that is nx1. This assignment statement takes place within a for loop as follows:

```
% Before iterating, I define an array of indices where I want to store the 
% data sets in timeData. This choice of storage location is for 
% organizational purposes.

A = [2, 5, 9, 21, 34, 100]; % Notice they are in ascending order, but have 
                            % gaps that have no predictability.
sizeA = size(A);
numIter = A(1);

for m = 1:numIter % numIter is the number of data sets that I need to store 
                  % in timeData 

  % At this point, some code that is entirely irrelevant to my question 
  % generates a nx1 array of data. One example of this data array is below. 

  data = [1.1;2.3;5.5;4.4]; % This is one example of what data could be. Its 
                            % number of rows, n, changes each iteration, as 
                            % do its contents.

  B = size(data);
  timeData(1:B(1),1,A(m)) = num2cell(data);
end
```

This code does put all contents of data in the appropriate locations within `timeData` as I want. However, it also adds `{0x0 double}` rows to all 2D arrays of `timeData(:,:,a)` for any `a` whose corresponding number of rows `n` was not the largest number of rows. Thus, there are many of these 2D arrays that have 10 to a couple hundred 0-valued rows that I don't want. For values of `a` that did not have a corresponding data set, the content of `timeData(:,:,a)` is an nx1 array of `{0x0 double}`.

I need to iterate over the contents of `timeData` in subsequent code, and I need to be able to find the size of the data set that is in `timeData(:,:,a)` without somehow discounting all the `{0x0 double}`.

How can I modify my assignment statement to fix this?

Edit: **Desired output of the above example is the following with n = 5. Let this data set be represented by a = 9.**

```
timeData(:,:,9) = {[1.1]}
                  {[2.3]}
                  {[5.5]}
                  {[8.6]}
                  {[4.4]}
```

Now, consider the possibility that a previous or subsequent value of the A matrix had a `data` set with n = 7, and n = 7 is the largest `data` set (largest n value). `timeData(:,:,9)` outputs like so in my code:

```
timeData(:,:,9) = {[1.1]}
                  {[2.3]}
                  {[5.5]}
                  {[8.6]}
                  {[4.4]}
                  {[0x0 double]}
                  {[0x0 double]}
```

@Dev-iL, as I understand it, your answer gives me the ability to delete the cells that have `{[0x0 double]}` in them (this is what I mean by "discounting"). This is a good plan B, but is there a way to prevent the `{[0x0 double]}` cells from showing up in the first place?

Edit 2: Update to the above statement "your answer gives me the ability to delete the cells that have `{[0x0 double]}` in them (this is what I mean by "discounting")". The `cellfun(@isempty... )` function makes the `{[0x0 double]}`cells go to `{[0x0 cell]}`, it does not remove them. In other words, `size(timeData(:,:,9))` is the same before and after the command is performed. This is not what I want. I want `size(timeData(:,:,9))` to be 5x1 no matter what n is for any other value of a.

Edit 3: I just realized that the most desired output would be the following:

```
timeData(:,:,9) = {[1.1;2.3;5.5;8.6;4.4]} % An n x 1 column matrix within 
                                          % the cell.
```

but I can work with this outcome or the outcome as described above.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "_without somehow discounting all the `{0x0 double}`_". Would you like your cell array to have empty cells instead of empty `double` arrays? Could you please specify the expected result (either of `timeData` or the subsequent element count) for the example you provided in the question? I have a feeling you can keep the assignment as it is, and just count the nonempty data intelligently afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't understand the structure of your dataset, which is why I can't suggest a better assignment method. However, I'd like to point out an operation that can you help deal with your data after it's been created:

```
cellfun(@isempty,timeData);
```

What the above does is return a `logical` array the size of `timeData`, indicating which cells contain something "empty". Typically, an array of arbitrary datatype is considered "empty" when it has at least one dimension that is equal to `0`.

How can you use it to your advantage?

```
%% Example 1: counting non-empty cells:
nData = sum(~cellfun(@isempty,timeData(:)));

%% Example 2: assigning empty cells in place of empty double arrays:
timeData(cellfun(@isempty,timeData)) = {{}};
```